# Apache mod_proxy_hcheck redirect to URL if all members are down

Tags: apache

Is it possible to tell Apache's `mod_proxy_hcheck` to perform a 302 redirect to a URL if all balancer members are offline?

For example, I'd like to redirect the user to `https://maint.example.com` if all the members in the below config are down:

```
<Proxy balancer://foo>
  BalancerMember http://www.example.com/  hcmethod=HEAD hcexpr=ok234 hcinterval=10
  BalancerMember http://www2.example.com/ hcmethod=HEAD hcexpr=ok234 hcinterval=10
</Proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache shows a 503 Service Unavailable error page if all balancer members are down.  So the solution is to add the following line to the vhost:

```
ErrorDocument 503 https://maint.example.com
```